# Adding panner / spacial audio to Web Audio Context from a WebRTC stream not working

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api

I would like to create a Web Audio panner to position the sound from a WebRTC stream.

I have the stream connecting OK and can hear the audio and see the video, but the panner does not have any effect on the audio (changing panner.setPosition(10000, 0, 0) to + or - 10000 makes no difference to the sound).

This is the onaddstream function where the audio and video get piped into a video element and where I presume i need to add the panner.

There are no errors, it just isn't panning at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
  peer_connection.onaddstream = function(event) {

        var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        var audioCtx = new AudioContext();

        audioCtx.listener.setOrientation(0,0,-1,0,1,0)

        var panner = audioCtx.createPanner();
        panner.panningModel = 'HRTF';
        panner.distanceModel = 'inverse';
        panner.refDistance = 1;
        panner.maxDistance = 10000;
        panner.rolloffFactor = 1;
        panner.coneInnerAngle = 360;
        panner.coneOuterAngle = 0;
        panner.coneOuterGain = 0;

        panner.setPosition(10000, 0, 0); //this doesn't do anything

        peerInput.connect(panner);
        panner.connect(audioCtx.destination);


        // attach the stream to the document element
        var remote_media = USE_VIDEO ? $("<video>") : $("<audio>");
        remote_media.attr("autoplay", "autoplay");
        if (MUTE_AUDIO_BY_DEFAULT) {
            remote_media.attr("muted", "false");
        }
        remote_media.attr("controls", "");
        peer_media_elements[peer_id] = remote_media;
        $('body').append(remote_media);
        attachMediaStream(remote_media[0], event.stream);



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the event stream before setting the panner

```
  var source  = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(event.stream);
```

Reference: [Mozilla Developer Network - AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource)

CreatePaneer Refernce: [Mozilla Developer Network - createPanner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createPanner)

3rd Party Library: [wavesurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/panner/index.html)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions - it doesn't seem to make any difference though :( any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all the options you've set for the panner node and see if that helps.  (The cone angles seem a little funny to me, but I always forget how they work.)
2. If that doesn't work, create a smaller test with the panner but use a simple oscillator as the input.  Play around with the parameters and positions to make sure it does what you want.
3. Put this back into your app.  Things should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out for myself.

The problems was not the code, it was because I was connected with Bluetooth audio.

Bluetooth apparently can only do stereo audio with the microphone turned off. As soon as you activate the mic, that steals one of the channels and audio output downgrades to mono.

If you have mono audio, you definitely cannot do 3D positioned sound, hence me thinking the code was not working.